# Identify first occurence of event based on multiple criterias

Tags: excel, powerpivot, flags, dax, find-occurrences

I have a dataset in PowerPivot and need to find a way to flag ONLY the first occurrence of a customer sub event

Context: Each event (COLUMN A) can have X number of sub events (COLUMN B), 
I already have a flag that identifies a customer event based on multiple criteria's (COLUMN D)... What I need is a way to flag **only the first occurrence** of a customer sub event within each event, I've added a *fake* COLUMN E to illustrate how the flagging should work.

[image]

UPDATE
Additional situation - Having duplicated customer sub_events but only need to flag the first sub_event... should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Only customer events will be flagged, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calculated column in your model using the following expression:

```
=
IF (
    [Customer_Event] = 1
        && [Sub_Event]
            = CALCULATE (
                FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'Table'[Sub_Event], 0 ),
                FILTER (
                    'Table',
                    'Table'[Event] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Event] )
                        && [Customer_Event] = 1
                )
            ),
    1,
    0
)
```

If `Sub_Event` column is a number replace `FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'Table'[Sub_Event], 0 )` by `MIN('Table'[Sub_Event])`

Also if your machine regional settings use `;` (semicolon) as list separator replace every `,` (comma) in my expression by a semicolon in order to match your settings.

**UPDATE:** Repeated values in `Sub_Event` column.

I think we can use `CaseRow#` column to get the first occurence of `Sub_Event` value:

```
=
IF (
    [Customer_Event] = 1
        && [Sub_Event]
            = CALCULATE (
                FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'Table'[Sub_Event], 0 ),
                FILTER (
                    'Table',
                    'Table'[Event] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Event] )
                        && [Customer_Event] = 1
                )
            )
        && [CaseRow#]
            = CALCULATE (
                MIN ( 'Table'[CaseRow#] ),
                FILTER (
                    'Table',
                    'Table'[Event] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Event] )
                        && [Customer_Event] = 1
                )
            ),
    1,
    0
)
```

It is not tested but should work.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This works on almost every line item, but (there's always a but)... I did not mention the fact that a sub_event can have duplicates, and what differentiate the first sub event is COLUMN C... how do I add an additional criteria so the calculation only flags the first sub_event.

Comment: @MarceloAguilar, do you mean you could have a repeated sub_event for one event? If so the column C will flag both sub_events as client events?

Comment: Yes... I updated my original question and added an image to illustrate my point.

Comment: @MarceloAguilar, I've updated my answer adding a new expression that take in account duplicated `Sub_Events`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!